# python chr(128) not converting decimal values greater than 127

Tags: python, chr

python chr(128) not converting decimal values greater than 127 showing the below mentioned character

```
chr(128)
�
```

I am new to python. Please help me

Comment: `char()` takes values from 0 to 255 (256 total values) corresponding to the ascii characters, and translating them into characters.

Comment: what do you actually expect? what is your code? and what is your problem / why is that behaviour a problem to you?

Comment: actually my idle shows the euro currency symbol '\x80' => €

Comment: This is entirely dependent on your terminal encoding (and python version; in python 3 the argument is a Unicode codepoint).

Answer (score 1):

I have added the below mentioned condition in my code which worked for me.

```
if decValue > 127:             
    charValue = unichr(decValue)

else:    
    charValue = chr(decValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is actually converting it, and it is `chr()`'s expected behavior!

```
>>> chr(128)
'\x80'
>>> print chr(128)
?
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the device you use to display that value: does it support that char?

In my DOS window:

```
>>> chr(128)
'\x80'
>>> print chr(128)
Ç
>>> print chr(129)
ü
```